# Microsoft Bot FormFlow Prompt Missing Date or Time

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot that uses a FormFlow dialog to collect some information, one of which is the built in DateTime. It is working great but if the input is a date and not a time it defaults to 12am on the correct date - is there a way to have it prompt for a time as well?
Similarly is there a way to prompt a date if the input is only a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate date and time field and skip the time field if specified when doing date.